# Dependencies issues in package.json when trying to install firebase in react project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, loader

**REACT, FIREBASE**

Hey guys!

Did any of you encounter this problem when you install something in the terminal but the dependencies in your package.json file did not update and you get an error about the loader?

I'm trying to use **firebase** in **react** (after number of recommendations as I'm trying to store some audio files for a volunteering project that i do and it's my first time handling something that is not a frontend), found a tutorial to follow but stuck with this issue!

I had an issue that mentioned the loader as well when I tried using the google API on the first version of the project I'm working on. Chat GPT and Google are not very helpful right now

Thank you!

This is my error:

```
./node_modules/idb/build/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (90:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| }
| replaceTraps((oldTraps) => ({
|     ...oldTraps,
|     get: (target, prop, receiver) => getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.get(target, prop, receiver),
|     has: (target, prop) => !!getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.has(target, prop),
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gilli-lessons",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "d": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "uui": "^1.0.7",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase": "^10.0.0",
    "netlify-cli": "^15.8.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried these 3 options (the last 2 I found that were meant to help after I got the error):

```
npm install firebase
npm install firebase --save
npm install firebase --save-dev
```

I want to be able to use firebase so i can use it to upload audio files for a project.

Comment: Also running into this issue! Were you able to figure it out?